# Aux port '12 Pathfinder not going in all the way

Tags: electrical, nissan, audio

So I have a Pathfinder and the stock has an auxiliary port when I got it (used), but the 3.5 cords that I insert into them doesn't go in all the way, and I'm giving it quite a bit of pressure. I'm not sure what's wrong but I don't see anything stuck in it or anything. Any ideas?

Also, is this under warranty and if not, how much does fixing this cost?

Comment: This is a long shot, but are you sure the cord you're trying to insert into the AUX port has a standard stereo 3.5mm / 1/8" connector?  There are longer versions of the 3.5mm plug that are used on a number of iPod cables, and probably others, to carry video or a microphone signal as well as audio.

Comment: its a standard male to male 3.5 cord. http://www.amazon.com/Parts-Express-3-5mm-Stereo-Cable/dp/B002T4OMG8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixing this shouldn't cost you more than $10-20 parts and labor combined. If you bought it from a dealer recently they should take care of it for free. If not you just need to complain a bit to the manager.

Comment: I called a local Nissan dealer, not the dealer I bought it from since it was 50 miles away, and they said they will take care of it since it's under manufacturers warranty. I'll update what they did and how they did it...

Comment: They couldn't tell me what was wrong initally, but I'll ask again. They said they are ordering the part for it, and said it was under factory warranty (not sure if it really is) bc car only has 8500 miles on it

Comment: Most vehicles have a three year bumper to bumper warranty so yes that is possible.

Comment: brought it to Nissan and they fixed it under warranty.